# Data consumption for on-demand map downloading

Tags: android, ios, here-api

We are developing a native app for android and iOS and are using here maps as map supplier.

The functionality in question is pretty similar to a navigation system (user can move around the map, choose start and destination, gets turn-by-turn navigation for his route).
We are not working with offline map functionality, but instead the data is downloaded on demand.
The problem is, that the data consumption is very high. Zooming out of the city and then zooming into another city nearby, results in about 30 mb of data downloaded. (Google Maps for comparison, needs about 3 mb).

Here Maps has three different downloading approaches (predefined map packages, bounding boxes and on-demand) as stated in there guide [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/map-data.html).

As map packages occupy a lot of space on the users mobile phones, we are aiming for the on demand solution.

We tried reducing the amount of information which is download (e.g. outlinings of mountains etc.), but apparently map data always gets downloaded beforehand and you can only change what details are rendered for the user.

At the moment i am looking for different approaches, which might further reduce the data consumption in any way. Ideas or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The quality/details of HERE data is high - that is why we the data size is higher.
There are no common ways how to decrease them.

But I would like to notice that mSDK provides caching mechanism and if data was loaded once we do not request it's again. So if a user backs to the city - we do not load the map again.
The size of the cache can be extended up to 2Gb.